# Using an I2C 16x2 LCD with a MSP432 microcontroller in C Code

Tags: embedded, code-composer

I am having trouble using a MSP432 and a I2C LCD. I have never used an I2C specific LCD and could use some help. All the libraries I saw strictly use C++ but I am going to need a C library. The current compiler I use is Code Composer Studio. I understand this is a broad question but if I could receive any help on being able to display text to my LCD, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At present, the question is too vague. Because it doesn't specify the part number of the LCD. Secondly, it doesn't show any code/program which people can have  a look at.

Comment: You appear to be asking for a library, which is off-topic on SO.  Your google-foo needs work.  It took no more than "MSP432 i2C library" to find https://github.com/hunterhedges/I2cLcd second on the list.  Not perhaps the way I'd do it - I'd suggest separating the generic I2C stuff from the LCD specific stuff, so you have a driver for other I2C devices, but as is it does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I have already found that github resource a long time ago. The only issue I see is that you need to run a program like teraterm alongside your code and whatever you enter into the console will print to the LCD. That is not my goal of my project. I was hoping to make a door lock that displays a password as a keypad is entered. I have everything completed but the LCD screen as I am struggling to use it. Thank you for the help anyways.